# Is there any verse in Quran that suggests all humans are made equal?

Tags: quran, equality

Is there any verse in Quran that suggests all humans are made equal (equal in the sense of what they are given in the world, the hardships would face and other things combined making each person equal)?

For example, one of the person is given high wealth but has some other thing less (like he has less good relationships) like he is being tested.

There is another person who has less wealth but has great relationships and is also being tested.

Together if you see both they both are given equal in life.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: We're equal in some senses, but also different in many.

> [**Baqara: 286**](https://quran.com/2/286)
>
> *لَا يُكَلِّفُ اللَّهُ نَفْسًا إِلَّا وُسْعَهَا ۚ* Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity.

Meaning each soul has a certain capacity.

Even for a single person has different capacities at different times: 
Our abilities change by: age, health, hunger, mental status, location, etc.

Other than the above verse, two keywords come to mind. If you search in Qur'an you'll find multiple examples:

- *بعضهم علی بعض* preferred one over the other
- *فضّلناهم* I preferred

> [Nisa' 34](https://quran.com/4/34)
>
> *الرِّجَالُ قَوَّامُونَ عَلَى النِّسَاءِ بِمَا فَضَّلَ اللَّهُ بَعْضَهُمْ عَلَىٰ بَعْضٍ*
>
> Men are the maintainers of women for that Allah has preferred in
>   bounty one of them over another

Another verse:

> [Nahl: 71](https://quran.com/16/71)
>
> *وَاللَّهُ فَضَّلَ بَعْضَكُمْ عَلَىٰ بَعْضٍ فِي الرِّزْقِ ۚ فَمَا الَّذِينَ فُضِّلُوا بِرَادِّي رِزْقِهِمْ عَلَىٰ مَا مَلَكَتْ
>   أَيْمَانُهُمْ فَهُمْ  فِيهِ سَوَاءٌ ۚ أَفَبِنِعْمَةِ اللَّهِ
>   يَجْحَدُونَ*
>
> Allah has bestowed His gifts of sustenance more freely on some of you
>   than on others: those more favoured are not going to throw back their
>   gifts to those whom their right hands possess, so as to be equal in
>   that respect. Will they then deny the favours of Allah?

And many more verses.

Answer (score 2):

(This answer is for the unedited version of the question)

From my observation this one is closest

> Al-Hujurat (49:13)
>
> Sahih International: O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the question is talking about equality in terms of difficulty of life or difficulty of Allah's test.

The answer to that is clearly no.

A simple evidence is that we are told to make the following dua:

> [...] Lord, do not burden us as You burdened those before us. [...] (2:286)

And according to the Prophet (SAW), Allah accepted the dua.

This dua refers to the tests and difficulties put on previous nations like the Jews and Christians. We are told to pray to Allah to not make us go through tests of the same magnitude.

That proves that not all people have the same difficulty in life. Some people can have more, and some people can have less.

Another evidence that proves different people are tested to different levels:

> Saad ibn Abi Waqqas narrated that he said: "O Messenger of Allah(s.a.w)! Which of the people is tried most severely?" He said: "The Prophets, then those nearest to them, then those nearest to them. A man is tried according to his religion; if he is firm in his religion, then his trials are more severe, and if he is frail in his religion, then he is tried according to the strength of his religion. The servant shall continue to be tried until he is left walking upon the earth without any sins." ([Sunan Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2398))

However, we can say with certainty that on the Day of Judgement everything will be equalized. Meaning, the one who is tested more will get more reward, so it will be worth it for him.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Quran states that all are born equal. Means that we are all from the same descendant of Adam. But what actually means equal? Other AYATS states some are higher than others and some are stronger than others and some are provided sustenance more over others. If you read these Ayat then the question arise how are we born equal if that’s the case?
```

Many scholars fail to answer them. They say Allah doesn’t burden anyone but to its capacity and so on. Did you ever think when Allah said that All are born as equal and Prophet’s hadith pbuh also states same like white have no superiority over blacks and so on.
First think you have to remember that there are some people who are born blind, dead, dumb, intellectually challenged and physically challenged. Then how are we equal?
When Allah and his prophet pbuh stating that All are born as equal. It actually means that The creator of everything and beyond has created All as equal. In what sense? In the sense that all Human has a SOUL. None are born without a soul. In this sense the soul/rooh that all are created equal.
Hope I was able to make you understand. And Allah knows the best.